# Retrosynthesis of (1S,2R)‐1‐isopropyl‐2,4‐dimethylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, regioselectivity, retrosynthesis

I think that retrosynthesis of (1*S*,2*R*)‐1‐isopropyl‐2,4‐dimethylcyclohexane involves the opening of an epoxide, to control the regiochemistry in order to achieve the *trans*-configuration via an S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism — which could be made from a C=C double bond. Would it be plausible to assume that the original cyclohexene is commercially available?

[image: (1S,2R)‐1‐isopropyl‐2,4‐dimethylcyclohexane]

Comment: Are you looking for both epimers? A single enantiomer or a racemate? Your effort is rather vague. Look into monoterpenes such as limonene and pulegone.

Comment: If you are unconcerned about the undefined stereocenter and a racemic product is acceptable, you might think about a Diels-Alder reaction. You may self-answer your question. Get back to us.

Comment: Do you mean to imply a single enantiomer or the racemate including the 1R,2S enantiomer? I think you mean the latter because the configuration at C4 is undefined. In any case a mixture of diastereomers would result. If a racemic mixture of diastereomers is OK, then follow the Diels-Alder route.